# Bash, Exec format Error

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, wine

I am trying to build and run program.

```
g++ -c source.cpp -o EIC
chmod u+x EIC
./EIC
bash:./EIC: Can not execute binary file: Exec format error.
```

`file EIC` displays:

```
EIC: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-x64, version 1(SYSV), not stripped
```

`uname -a` displays:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.18.0-193.el8.x86_x64 #1 SMP Fri May 8 10:59:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please tell me what's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

From `man g++`:

> ```
>    When you invoke GCC, it normally does preprocessing, compilation,
>    assembly and linking.  The "overall options" allow you to stop this
>    process at an intermediate stage.  For example, the -c option says not
>    to run the linker.  Then the output consists of object files output by
>    the assembler.
> ```

So, if you want `g++` to run the linker - to create an executable file rather than an object code file - you should remove the `-c` flag from your command.